# How to disable Magento_JwtUserToken

Tags: magento2, api, token

I want to disable Magento_JwtUserToken Module but it is showing following error

**bin/magento module:disable Magento_JwtUserToken**

```
Unable to change status of modules because of the following constraints:
Cannot disable Magento_JwtUserToken because modules depend on it:
Magento_AdobeStockAdminUi: Magento_AdobeStockAdminUi->Magento_AdminAdobeIms->Magento_JwtUserToken
Magento_AdminAdobeIms: Magento_AdminAdobeIms->Magento_JwtUserToken
```

I want to use the old API token system that were used in Magento 2.4.2 or previous versions

Any help suggestions regarding this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable all dependent modules as well: Magento_JwtUserToken, Magento_AdobeStockAdminUi, Magento_AdminAdobeIms

like:

```
magento module:disable Magento_JwtUserToken Magento_AdobeStockAdminUi Magento_AdminAdobeIms
```